# Refresh list after deleting item

Tags: node.js, angular

I got simple function which deleting file from server.

```
  deletePhoto(e) {
    if (window.confirm('Do you really need delete this file?')) {
      this.uploadService.deleteFile(e)
        .subscribe(res => {
          this.fetchFiles();
        });
    }
  }
```

Service looks like

```
 deleteFile(filename): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`http://localhost:8080/api/files/all/${filename}`)
  }
```

and function fetch looks like

```
fetchFiles() {
    this.fileUploads = this.uploadService.getOneFile(this.filename);
  }
```

and inside my backend

```
exports.deleteFile = (req, res) => {
    fs.unlink((uploadFolder + '_files/') + req.params.filename, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("failed to delete local image:" + err);
        } else {
            console.log('successfully deleted local image');
        }
    });
}
```

Deleting works fine but after delete my list not refreshing.

"List" it's simple table

```
<tr *ngFor="let file of fileUploads | async | filter: name | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10,
                        currentPage: p }; let i = index">
                  <td id="lPart" style="cursor: pointer; font-weight: normal;">
                    <a href="http://localhost:8080/api/file/{{file}}">{{file}}</a></td>
                  <td class="text-right" id="action">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" (click)="deletePhoto(file)">Delete</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

I want to refresh this table without reloading page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to not fetch your files after deleting. If your purpose is to have an application with users and users, any fetch to the API is time consuming, so fetching less mean being faster.

First, to be sure that you will have a response from your API, you need to change your sending method as below

```
exports.deleteFile = (req, res) => {
  fs.unlink((uploadFolder + '_files/') + req.params.filename, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("failed to delete local image:" + err);
      res.json({"message":"fail","code":500}) // this is an exemple, but you need to have at least res.json({})
    } else {
      console.log('successfully deleted local image');
      res.json({"message":"success","code":200}) // same here
    }
  });
}
```

After you send the file to your backend, just splice the file from your list as below

```
deletePhoto(e){
  if (window.confirm('Do you really need delete this file?')) {
    this.uploadService.deleteFile(e)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.fileUploads.splice(this.fileUploads.indexOf(filename),1)
      });
  }
}
```

But the problem is that your `fileUploads` is the `Observable`, so what could be possible to do is this

```
fetchFiles() {
  this.uploadService.getOneFile(this.filename).subscribe((val)=>{
    this.fileUploads = val
  }
}
```

This way you will have the list in your `fileUploads` variable, but then an ultimate change is needed on your template, you need to remove the pipe `async`

Comment: I tried this but: this.fileUploads.findIndex is not a function

Comment: ERROR TypeError: TestFile_F1093.jpg is not a function
    at Array.findIndex (<anonymous>)

Comment: Sorry my bad, try with `indexOf` instead of `findIndex`

Comment: list works fine but now I don't have any request to my api hmm :D I am just clicking delete, item is removed from list but api seems nothing.

Comment: Again my bad, it's normal, when you fetch the API, nothing happen while you don't subscribe to it. So I have edited with what I think will finally work well :)

Comment: I did it by myself but when I subscribe deleting files works fine but list doesn't change. Like before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220858/discussion-between-alexis-and-markez).